# No module named 'trax'

Tags: python, nlp, trax

[image]

Guys, Help we with this, I installed trax with pip install trax, but it showing error, after restarting the kernel also Getting this error.

Comment: maybe you have two Pythons installed and `pip` install modules for one Python but you run code with other Python. Pythons don't share modules. Maybe run `sys.executable` to get `/full/path/to/python` and later use `/full/path/to/python -m pip install trax`

Answer (score 0):

Try running followings

```
pip install --upgrade pip

pip install --upgrade "jax[cpu]"

pip install trax
```